# How to fix UPDATE API for Netsuite to Salesforce Flow?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a Netsuite to Salesforce Item Flow Integration. After Creating the item in Salesforce the Item Id is updated back to Netsuite. But this is causing the poll activity to pick the same record again. Here the poll update expression used is:

```
#[server.dateTime.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")].
```

I used DataWave 1.0 and here is my code:

---

```
{
    (internalId : flowVars.setNSPayload.internalId) when ((payload.success[0] == true ) and (sessionVars.itemiD == null)),
    (externalId : payload[0].id) when ((payload.success[0] == true ) and (sessionVars.itemiD == null)),
    (customFieldList: {
        customField: [{
            StringCustomFieldRef__custitem_id: payload[0].id,
            StringCustomFieldRef__custitem_upy_error:''
        }]
    })when ((payload.success[0] == true ) and (sessionVars.itemiD == null)),

    (internalId : flowVars.setNSPayload.internalId) when ((payload.success[0] == false ) and (sessionVars.itemiD == null)),
    (externalId : payload[0].id) when ((payload.success[0] == false ) and (sessionVars.itemiD == null)),
    (customFieldList: {
        customField: [{
            StringCustomFieldRef__custitem_upy_error: "Error MSG:" ++ payload[0].errors[0].message  ++ "Status Code: " ++ payload[0].errors[0].statusCode 
        }]
    })when ((payload.success[0] == false ) and (sessionVars.itemiD == null))
}
```

I expect the poll to not pick this record after it has updated the in netsuite

How to solve this?

Comment: Just change the format of the datetime. Because item datetime is not matching with netsuit datetime format.

Comment: Hi but the poll picks Data correctly, the issue is with the Update API.

Comment: You only show the de script but not the poll. Please add more details

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help you. You can use [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toisostring) method:

```
var dt = new Date("1 Novenber 2019 15:08 UTC");
document.write(dt.toISOString());

// Output:
//  2019-11-01T15:08:00.000Z
```

Comment: I dont think this will help